# UIPageControl : How to dynamically load controls in View in iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipagecontrol, iphone-sdk-4.1

I am making an iPhone app which has a requirement to implement the UIPageControl.

I have referred to many tutorials but all of them have added static data to view. I want to dynamically add buttons to the view when the new view is swiped in.

What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add new items to UIView, using addSubview/removeFromSuperview methods.